# Can't switch off YouTube dark mode

Tags: youtube, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions, cookies, cache

I can't switch off YouTube dark mode; the image here explains it:

[image]

Can someone help? Restarting the browser doesn't help. If I switch mode and restart it, it is dark again.

Answer (score 0):

- go to **`chrome://extensions/`** and check for extensions that may be forcing dark mode preference
- then press <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`SHIFT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`DELETE`**</kbd> and delete cookies which may store the dark mode preference because you are not loged in into YouTube

Answer (score 0):

You can try clearing the cache, cookies... Try a different browser. Try in incognito mode. Try removing any scripts you have on YouTube to see if that is causing the issue. Try a different account. Use CCleaner. Restart computer.

Hopefully one of these will help with the issue.